# Barplot with set x, y and fill categories R

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, bar-chart

I have the following type of data and would like to create a stacked barplot, which would show the sum of `Number` on y axis for different bins of `Distance` on x axis which would indicate distance. In fact, that would be a sort of histogram, but not with frequencies on y but the sums of `Number` per set bin. This would be cumulative for all categories in `Dest` which would be marked with different colours.
Thanks so much.

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(c(rep("A",20),rep("B",25),rep("C",35)),sample(1:30, 80,replace = TRUE),
                 rnorm(80,45,8))
colnames(df) <- c("Dest","Number","Distance")

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Distance, y = Number, fill = Dest)) + 
        geom_histogram(colour = c("red","blue","green"))
```

Comment: Try replacing `y = Number` with `weight = Number` in `aes()`. Does that give what you want? As for the colour mappings, you can move them out of `geom_histogram()` & specify them in `scale_fill_manual()` instead.

Comment: Thank you @Z.Lin it worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are 2 solutions in case you want to be the one that specifies the (`Distance`) bins and not the histogram:

**Option 1** (using `ntile`)

Here's a solution that allows you to specify the number of bins using `ntile`, which means that those bins will have more or less the same number of observations:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(c(rep("A",20),rep("B",25),rep("C",35)),sample(1:30, 80,replace = TRUE),
                 rnorm(80,45,8))
colnames(df) <- c("Dest","Number","Distance")


df %>%
  group_by(bin = ntile(Distance, 3)) %>%    # specify number of bins you want  
  mutate(DistRange = paste0(round(min(Distance)), " - ", round(max(Distance)))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(Dest, bin, DistRange = fct_reorder(DistRange, bin)) %>%
  summarise(sum_number = sum(Number)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  ggplot(aes(DistRange, sum_number, fill=Dest))+
  geom_col()
```

[image]

**Option 2** (using `cut`)

An alternative option using `cut` to specify ranges:

```
df %>%
  mutate(bin = cut(Distance, breaks = c(min(Distance)-1, 40, 50, 55, max(Distance)))) %>%  # specify ranges
  group_by(Dest, bin) %>%
  summarise(sum_number = sum(Number)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  ggplot(aes(bin, sum_number, fill=Dest))+
  geom_col()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Any idea why I receive strange ranges when I apply it to my own data. If I specify 10 bins, i get the following ranges:
0-0, 0-1, 1-1, 1-2, 10-100, 2-2, 2-3, 2-5, 5-10.
I wonder why they are not in increasing order?

Comment: The process uses them as `factor` variables and compares the first character. That's why `10-100` goes before `2-2`. I'll try to update my answer...

Comment: Check again. I've added `fct_reorder(DistRange, bin)` which will solve the problem.